# Can I use prototypes in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

Can I use JavaScript prototypes in JavaScript Controller Lightning Component?

Comment: I suspect that this may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info). We're generally restricted from using prototype because we could subvert security or introduce difficult to trace bugs, since types are cached for performance reasons and locked down for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use javascript prototypes in our component. We added it to static resource js library with rest of code.